# Managing lots of backbone async requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, asynchronous

I am building a single page web application. When a user for example opens a case in the application, I need to load various data asynchronously.

However, I only want to present the case to the user when all that data has finished loading.

I currently use Backbone to fetch collections of data asynchronously.

Is there any standard or usual way of possibly registering various fetches and getting an event when they have all completed?

I'm considering building an elaborate system of bools to do this but I am wondering if maybe there is not some plugin that already does this.

The basic idea is:
Register a bunch of backbone fetches and associate them with somthing like `load:case:data`

When all of those fetches complete, I get an event like `load:case:data` completed. At that point I can listen to that event and display the case.

Comment: `Promise.all` is the function you're looking for. It's more of a standardization than a single library, so look into The Minister's recommendation of Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the Q promise Library (`Q.all`) or BlueBird (`Promise.all`) and then you can just sync the promises returned from the fetch methods.

You can also use plain jQuery when to do that. e.g.:

```
$.when(someCollection.fetch(), anotherCollection.fetch()).done(function(){
   // All Completed, do next thing
});
```

One thing you can also use as an alternative to Q, BlueBird and jQuery is native `Promise.all` ES6 approach, look at the following table for support, and see if it matches your target browsers.

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: How can I use the when method of Jquery if I have an Array of Backbone.Collection?

Comment: you can use the old-good JavaScript `apply` method, and apply your array to the $.when method.

Comment: Worth noting that ES6 also has `Promise.all`

Comment: @Milo $.when.apply(null, promiseArr).done(function(){ }). Every fetch request returns a promise, and you can just put them in an array and pass to the $.when function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Promise`s will certainly work for this, but you'll need to promisify your async functions. Where you used to work like this:

```
asynFunction(function(data) {
    //callback
    //data is finished.
});
```

Now you need to work like this:

```
var prom = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    asynFunction(resolve);
});
prom.then(function(data){
     //data is here
});
```

With `Promise.all` you can dispatch all promises:

```
var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    asynFunction1(resolve);
});

var prom2 = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    asynFunction2(resolve);
});

var prom3 = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    asynFunction3(resolve);
});

var pall = Promise.all([prom1, prom2, prom3]);
pall.then(function(values){
    //values is an array with the result of every promise.
    //this function won't be called until all promises have been resolved.
});
```

There are a couple of alternatives to `Promise`, if I remember correctly Async.js also works for this.